# web push notification is not appearing in chrome

Tags: javascript, push-notification

I have started implementing web push notification in a web application.

Got Steps from [Google Post Here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/#subscribe_the_user)

But the notifications don't appear in chrome browser. Also, I have used the code and integrated into my application and the notifications appear in Firefox but not in chrome.

I doubt, in registered service worker, the `self.addeventlistener('push', option)` is not working properly in chrome.

Any ideas

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you implemented, then tell us what exactly isn't working in Chrome (it's unclear what "not working properly" means).

Comment: @Parithi try the following [demo](https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/) to see whether this is working on your browser

Comment: Hi @kay, I have followed the steps given in 
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/

Comment: Hi @HyyanAboFakher, The demo which you have sent isn't working. It asked for subscription, and i allowed it. I tried sending a push using that button and i dont receive anything. I tried teh same in Firefox and it worked.

Comment: @HyyabAboFakher indeed its not working for me either. Did you maybe found a why or a fix? Firefox works flawlessly even on mobile. But chrome neither on desktop nor mobile.

Comment: not working for me, even clicking 'view demo' button on pushjs.org is not showing notification on chrome, working in firefox, any idea or fix ?

Answer (score 1):

System Settings -> System -> Notifications -> turn on for Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I implemented everything correctly but was also wondering why I don't receive any notifications. Even when I googled for "webpush notification test" and used some websites to send me push notifications, so I would know if I am missing something in my code.

So, on mac you would specifially need to enable it in the system settings for Chrome and also I am using DND most of the time which also supresses notifications. Be sure to turn that off when you're testing sending push notifications and for good UX to inform the user about it. Most may not know.